# Why is this the window object in a Vue method even with an Arrow function

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple [Vue app](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/218400/) that looks like this...

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value:""
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.test(10);
  },
  methods: {
    test: (max) =>{
        console.log(this)
    }
  }
})
```

Console outputs window I would expect it to be the Vue Application. How do I structure it so that this is Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is `window` *especially* in your arrow function.

Use a normal `function` declaration, or the equivalent [ES2015 method declaration shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: "test"
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.test(10);
    this.test2(42);
    this.test3(42);
  },
  methods: {
    // Arrow function: `this` is the context when declaring.
    test: (max) => {
      console.log(this === window)
    },
    // Function expression: `this` is the context when calling.
    // Bound to the Vue instance by Vue.
    test2: function(max) {
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    // ES6 method shorthand, same as above.
    test3(max) {
      console.log(this.value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```